# Stop EPiServer trying to serve requests to my virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, episerver

We have a site built in EPiServer and is running on www.mysite.com

Now we have built a small .NET microsite that isn’t part of the EPiServer project that we would like to run as a IIS Virtual Directory www.mysite.com/microsite

At the moment we are seeing 404 being returned for all of the assets on the microsite so www.mysite.com/microsite/assets/js/myjs.js or www.mysite.com/microsite/assets/img/myimg.jpg

The home page of the microsite is served, but with missing assets.Is there a way I can configure the main EPiServer project to ignore all of the requests to my microsites folder structure.

Comment: MVC, i believe we have solved the problem i will answer below

Comment: Yup, please add the answer if you found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while battling this issue we have now got a repeatable solution.

In the parent application (EPiServer solution) we need to add the following location element in the web.config

```
  <location path="MY-IIS-APPLICATION-NAME">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <clear />
        <add name="wildcard" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Then, in the same web.config we wrap the `<system.web>` and `<system.webserver>` sections with this element `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`

Finally we need to alter the web.config in our IIS-Application to unload the EPiServer handlers and libraries.

So, in the `<system.web>` section we added these elements

```
<httpModules>
  <clear />
</httpModules>

<httpHandlers>
  <clear />
</httpHandlers>
```

then within the `<system.webserver>` we make these changes/removals

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules>
  <remove name="InitializationModule" />
  <remove name="FirstBeginRequestModule" />
  <remove name="Initializer" />
  <remove name="WorkflowRuntime" />
  <remove name="UrlRewriteModule" />
  <remove name="ShellRoutingModule" />
  <remove name="ContainerDisposal" />
  <remove name="PropertyInjection" />
  <remove name="AttributedInjection" />
</modules>
```

There is every chance that this isn't the solution, but in the last few days we have rolled this out to 6 different projects and it has had the desired effect each time.